# Readme.Rmd causes push failure to github from Rstudio

Tags: r, github, rstudio

As long as the Readme.Rmd file was included in the project, Rstudio could not push to github, but kept reporting that all files were up to date, when in fact they were far out of date.

Only successful work-around was to take the Readme.Rmd file out of the project and hide it for later use.

This isn't a coding issue per say, but I tried including and not including Readme.Rmd in both the buildignore file and the gitignore file.

Hiding the file away ended hours of frustration. I just wanted to share this to help others and to somehow get the word out about this apparent bug. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You're _describing_ a situation, but not clearly _showing_ it to us. Much better than telling us what you think is happening would be to provide a [mcve]. As currently posed there's not much we can do here. Please read [ask].

Comment: Also, it sounds like you're conflating committing with pushing. An "all files are up to date" message would be about _committing_, a purely local operation. Pushing should never give this message; it deals only with already existing commits.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have an issue because of local changes in `Readme.Rmd`, you could ignore those changes with:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- Readme.Rmd
```

Then test again if your issue persists.